# How to use testr with karma-jasmine adapter?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner, testr

Everything works (Karama, Jasmine, Underscore, Backbone, testr) as evidenced by the _UnitTestUnitTest passing. **But simple testr statements always fail.**

***The basic _UnitTestUnitTest works!***

```
it('works for jquery', function() {
    expect( $("document")).toBeTruthy();
});

it('works for underscore', function() {
    expect(_.size([1,2,3])).toEqual(3);
});
it('works for backbone', function() {
    var model = Backbone.Model.extend();
    expect(model).toBeTruthy();
});
it('works for testr', function() {
    expect(testr).toBeTruthy();
});
```

However, in my other real unit test, it fails on the testr line:

`AccountSummaryCollection_CLASS = testr('models/sales-rep/AccountSummaryCollection');`

**I'm certain i'm including my dependency of 'models/sales-rep/AccountSummaryCollection' correctly in my config (I see it hosted and getting loaded by require.js deps!!!**

However, the big problem is it claims our application module is not loaded even though it is. I also tried to wrap the whole AccountSummaryUnitTest.js inside of `require([‘AccountSummaryCollection’], function(){….` This produces a new error where inside a dependency (AccountSummary.js) the error “Backbone is not defined” is thrown. That makes no sense in the context because obviously the AccountSummaryCollection has already resolved Backbone.Collection. **This bad resolution is what makes me suspect it is testr that is fishy.**

I also tried to manually include the  file using the karma config, but requirejs does not like that since it’s a conflicting define() function.

**Below:** `serving` actually means `Requested by Client` and the {{{dependency}}} file is my own trace to confirm they are added to the deps list in the karma-spec-runner.js.

It fails at this line:
AccountSummaryUnitCollection line 27: AccountSummaryCollection_CLASS = testr('models/sales-rep/AccountSummaryCollection');

**Here's the "spec runner" javascript** (basically copied from the docs, with some extra logging).

```
var dependencies = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        //
        if (/Test\.js$/.test(file)) {
            //traces my test files fine!
            console.log("{{{testing file}}} --> "+ file );
            dependencies.push(file);
        }
    }
}

// jam our application files into the deps
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {

        if (file.indexOf('src/main/app/') !== -1 ) {
            //traces my dep files fine!
            console.log("{{{dependency}}} file --> "+ file );
            dependencies.push(file);
        }
    }
}


require.config({
    baseUrl: 'base/src/main/app/',
    paths: {
        'resources'      : '../resources/',
        'jquery'         : '../resources/js/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min',
        'text'           : '../resources/js/lib/text-2.0.10',
        'i18n'           : '../resources/js/lib/i18n-2.0.4',
        'd3'             : '../resources/js/lib/d3.v3.1.10.min',
        'AppMeasurement' : '../resources/js/lib/appMeasurement',
        'underscore'     : '../resources/js/lib/underscore-1.5.2',
        'Backbone'       : '../resources/js/lib/backbone-1.1.2.min',
        'testr'          : '../../test/lib/testr'
    },
    deps: dependencies,
    shim: {
        d3: {
            exports: 'd3'
        },
        AppMeasurement: {
            exports: 'AppMeasurement'
        },
        underscore: {
            deps:["jquery"],
            exports: '_'
        },
        Backbone: {
            deps:["jquery"],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        testr:{
            exports: 'testr'
        }
    },
    callback: window.__karma__.start,
    locale: "en-us"
});
```

**Here's the karma section of my gruntfile**

```
karma: {
    unit: {
        background: false,
        options: {
            logLevel : 'debug',

            basePath:'./',

            // files for karma to host
            files: [

                {pattern: 'src/main/resources/js/lib/**/*.js', included: false, served: true},
                {pattern: 'src/main/resources/js/plugins/**/*.js', included:false, served: true },

                {pattern: 'src/test/lib/sinon.js', included: false },
                {pattern: 'src/test/lib/testr.js', included: false },

                {pattern: 'src/test/js/stubs/**/*.js', included: false, served: true},    

                // manually load our application unit test & deps to examine the simplest case
                {pattern:'src/main/app/models/sales-rep/AccountSummary.js', included: false },
                {pattern:'src/main/app/models/sales-rep/AccountSummaryCollection.js', included: false },

                {pattern: '_UnitTestUnitTest.js', included: false},
                {pattern: 'src/test/js/unit/AccountSummaryCollectionUnitTest.js', included: false},

                'src/test/js/karma-spec-runner.js'

            ],
            plugins: [
                "karma-jasmine",
                "karma-phantomjs-launcher",
                "karma-requirejs",
                'karma-chrome-launcher',
            ],
            frameworks: [
                "jasmine",
                "requirejs"
            ],
            browsers: [
                //"PhantomJS"
                "Chrome"
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

**Here's a sample test that *fails***

Note that the testr config is per unit test. Plus, this test WORKS in *plain in the browser jasmine!*

```
// tried with and without the leading require statement as noted in main question.
require( ['models/sales-rep/AccountSummaryCollection'], function() {

    describe('AccountSummaryCollectionUnitTest', function () {

        var AccountSummaryCollection_CLASS;
        function configureTestr() {
            testr.config({                
                whitelist: [
                    'models/sales-rep/AccountSummaryCollection',
                    'models/sales-rep/AccountSummary'
                ]
            });
        }

        beforeEach(function () {
            configureTestr();
            console.log("initializing AccountSummaryCollection_CLASS");
            //fails on following line
            AccountSummaryCollection_CLASS = testr('models/sales-rep/AccountSummaryCollection');
        });
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried using require("myModuleToBeTested", function(){  ... //unit test here ... and it also fails.

Comment: Do you have a small failing test case? Without having your application's source, it is difficult to follow what's happening, and to know whether it's specific to something in your application or to the Karma+Jasmine+Testr combo.

Comment: can you please post your `require` and `testr` configuration ? otherwise is quite hard to help you

Comment: I have updated with the karma config, the spec runner (which includes the require.config, a sample test that fails and the testr config within that test. Currently, each unit test has a testr configuration with its own whitelist.

Comment: I heard there's a bug with testr 1.3.x I dropped to 1.2 and that led to a slew of new errors.Moving on to Ruby + JSCover.

Comment: Wholly Molly. Figured it out after playing with versions...

Answer (score 0):

You need specific versions of libs to get it to work right:

- testr 1.0.2 (NOT 1.0.3!!!!!)
- Backbone 1.0.0 (not 1.1.2 for some reason)
- underscore 1.6
- require-2.1.11 [production]  (for some reason we had 2.1.2)

Then I had to `include:true` for underscore and backbone in the Karma config. Then the shim works with require 2.1.11 without the mismatched anonymous define error.

Additioanlly, to make sure to delay the test execution. I did not have luck with the waitSeconds (that just increases the test duration).

**The key part of the require config:**

```
    // since we are forcing Backbone in the dom instead of requiring it
    callback: function(){               
            setTimeout(function () {                    
                window.__karma__.start();
            }, 4000);
    },
```